# URL file path problems Swift 4

Tags: swift, file, url

I'm beginner in programming and I try to use URL to save the path of video files, but when I create the AVplayerItem with the URLs, it's doesn't work. Then I try to open only image which programmatic URL ans it's doesn't work to.

Can you help me to find the problem. Thanks

```
let myURL = URL(fileURLWithPath: "/Users/*userName*/Desktop/IMG_0248.JPG")
let image = NSImage(contentsOf: myURL)
print(image ?? "No image") // Always no image
imageView.layer?.contents = image
```

Comment: The app is sandboxed so you don't have access out of your app bundle directory

Comment: you can present a NSOpenPanel to the user and let him select the file

Comment: If you need to include images in your app you need to add them to the image assets or drag them into your project

Comment: Thanks for your answer, I'm starting has better understand the problem. This code is just a test, in my main app I use NSOpenPanel to open movie or image, and I save the URL's with NSCoding protocol. But when I try to open files with the stored URL it's doesn't work

Comment: You can turn off App Sandbox in your targets app capabilities

Comment: Thank you very much for your help, it works perfectly. I'll take the time to discover a little better App sandbox

Comment: No, the post didn't mention the code environment, it could be an iOS or macOS app.

Comment: Sorry the application it’s made for a mac OSX application. For 10.12